Why warning is displayed when one tries to change Product OWD?
Product OWD was released in 2022
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_products_sharing_defaults.htm&release=236&type=5
and if we try to change this, we receive the following warning alert

Warning: If you set organization-wide default sharing on products to a
value other than Public Read/Write, and you use custom code or
installed a package, unexpected behavior can occur. All sharing rules
will be recalculated based on the new defaults, which may require
significant time. The original values will be displayed until the
operation completes. An email notification will be sent upon
completion. Do you want to continue?


Why this warning is displayed and what exactly may break?

My guess is that some packages which have been developed before 2022 may not respect product sharing rules or may expect all products to be public

It feels like Salesforce could have ensured that Apex functioned consistently with original behaviour, based on class API version, but that they didn't - based on the given warning message. I suspect your guess is along the right lines.
